# How to do action when fragment is visible in viewPager?

Tags: android

[image]

**I have saved data in Sqlite Database, how to get it in next Fragment in ViewPager.**

```
private HashMap<String,String> prefernceHashMap; 
    try
    {
        dbOperation.open();
        prefernceHashMap = dbOperation.getPreference();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        dbOperation.close();
    }
```